# How important is Bankroll Management in Texas Hold'em Poker, and why?

Tags: poker, poker-texas-holdem

How important is Bankroll Management in Texas Hold'em Poker, and why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much important in Poker Texas Hold'em is "Dealer Position Offset"?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/107/how-much-important-in-poker-texas-holdem-is-dealer-position-offset)

Comment: yyyyyy, bankroll managment in poker is not connected to the position in hand, this is 2 other seperate things

Answer (score 15):

The bankroll is your safe haven. The bankroll is what makes you different from a gambler, betting, bet again, breaks and puts more money in the game.

The bankroll is a fundamental part of you being a poker player. Treat it with due importance.

The bankroll should be large. It's more than you think you need. It is much larger than you want it. The truth is that you need a lot.

Why you need a lot? Because of something called a variance.

You know that poker is a game of skill, but in the short term, luck plays a great importance. Even the best players end up having to go through hard times. This is part of the game and every player should be able to handle it.

The fact that your bankroll vary up and down over the course of the game is known as variance. The more aggressive style, the greater the variability. And the more you play a game of high variance (as MTT or 6-max), the greater the ups and downs will meet your bankroll.

There is no escaping the variance. Even if you are prudent and cautious, your bankroll will experience ups and downs.

When in high, it's just joy, but the low that you need a good bankroll. You need a box that allows you to resist the bad times without breaking. Because if you break, will not be able to enjoy the sound stage, which will certainly come back.

The bankroll should always be calculated in relation to buy-ins or stakes of the games you want to play.

A bankroll of $ 1000 can be big or little ... depends on the buy-in. If you're playing $ 5 SNG's (Sit and Go) tournament, this is a pretty good bankroll. Have to play $ 50 SNGs, it is little.

A bankroll of $ 2000 is big enough for you to face without fear NL cash tables 0.10 to 0.20. But the same bankroll can not stand the jolt of the NL tables 1-2.

There are methods to calculate the bankroll according to your ROI, ie its return on investment. I do not advise a beginner to use this method. To know your ROI and you need a good time and a lot of hands in poker tournaments or played (even many). Moreover, the game changes, changing tables, opponents change. Your ROI will not be the same as six months ago, it will fluctuate a lot over time.

So for those just starting out, I suggest being guided by the amount of buy-ins. It is simpler and is guaranteed.

As I said above, in relation to the bankroll, you better be cautious. Here are my recommendations:

**Cash games**

- 6-Max: 100 buy-ins

Down to level 60 with buy-ins

- Full Ring: 80 buy-ins

Down to level 55 with buy-ins

**Tournaments**

- Sit and Go: 50 buy-ins

Level down to 30 buy-ins

- MTT: 100 buy-ins

Down to level 60 with buy-ins

---

These numbers mean the minimum number of buy-ins that you must have to a certain level and when you should go down a level.

For example, if you want to play SNG tournaments of $ 2, your bankroll should be $ 100. If your bankroll drops to $ 60 or less, switch to the $ 1 SNG.

If you want to play $ 10 SNG, the bankroll should be $ 500. The bankroll has dropped below $ 300? Change to the $ 5 SNG. No need to take into account the rake calculation.

In cash games, is the same thing with just one more detail: if you play with full stack, the value of each buy-in is the sum of 100 big blinds. If you are a shortstacker each buy-in is worth 20 big blinds.

So if you want to play 6-max 0.10-0.20, your bankroll should be $ 2000. If your bankroll drops below $ 1200, go to the games of 0.05-0.10.

If you are entering a shortstacker with 20% of the buy-in, your bankroll at 6-max from 010 to 0.20 to be $ 400. Where to stay under $ 240, get off of level.

Comment: great explanation. The important part of bankroll management is that 'playing scared' is going to cost you money in the long run. The important thing to consider when choosing a size of your bankroll is that you should be able to go broke at a table without it hurting you.

Comment: your cash game recommendations seem to be rather conservative to me. otherwise great answer!

Comment: I play with 50 buy-ins (of 100 big blinds), comfortably (cash games, 6-max).  Otherwise, great advice.

Comment: Great post. I would add that the need of bankroll depends largely on how important is the money to you. For pro/semi-pro the guidelines are pretty much along my experiences however recreational player can get by with much less.